# A web app to train the rasa chatbot from the custom web interface

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

i want to create a web app where the user can submit the intent and response for the questions and answers for the rasa based chatbot . can anyone help me out with how to build such web app to train the rasa chatbot from it by making api calls.
also can you explain the sort of apis i can use to train the chatbot ?